# Interfaces are not part of Object hierarchy in Java. Why ? Do they belong to some hierarchy?

Tags: java

I am preparing for an OCJP. I came across this statement in Kathy Sierra's book.

> Interfaces are not part of Object hierarchy in Java

I am just curious and want to know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to precise things a bit: 
An interface is not part of the object hierarchy, meaning that an interface which does not extend another one has no supertype.

However, an instance typed as an interface is always an `Object`, otherwise you would not be able to write things like:

```
interface MyInterface { //no supertype.
}
MyInterface var = new MyInterface(){};
var.toString(); //toString method is defined on Object class.
```

Comment: do they extend an (default/supertype interface) ?

Comment: No, see JLS : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.3 : While every class is an extension of class Object, there is no single interface of which all interfaces are extensions.

Answer (score 1):

as you know an `interface` can not inherits from any class, so it can not be inherited directly or indirectly from `Object` class, that's why an interface does not belongs to `Object` hierarchy like other classes for example String,etc